# ROS launch resource not found

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-hydro, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am using ROS-Industrial Training and I'm receiving these messages when attempting to launch the supplementary launch files:

```
raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: irb_2400_arm_navigation
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

I was previously using Groovy and never had this problem, if anyone could shed some light on this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217498/ros-launch-resource-not-found/) by [TheDude35](https://answers.ros.org/users/23839/thedude35/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

arm_navigation has been deprecated in hydro and replaced by moveit. There seem to be irb_2400 moveit packages. I'm not sure what the content of your tutorial is, but in any case, I'd recommend using moveit based tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheDude35](https://answers.ros.org/users/23839/thedude35/) on 2015-09-11**:
Okay and I did use a moveit based tutorial when creating my own moveit! package based on a URDF I exported from solidworks and received the same message when attempting to launch the launch files that were created. Any thoughts on that particular situation that doesn't involve a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@dornhege is right, but just to clarify: on Hydro you should follow the [Hydro version](http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/hydro/Exercises/) of the exercises. For Indigo there are also [updated exercises](http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/indigo/Exercises/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2